# i mongodb my date in 01-03-2016 00:12 formate how can i find data by using date

Tags: php, mongodb

```
"_id" : ObjectId("57e52983bdf2814f2eb4afb8"),
        "id" : 1066056,
        "msisdn" : NumberLong("919979866306"),
        "service_id" : "V3_BHOJF",
        "class" : "V3_BHOJF",
        "txnid" : NumberLong("6295769953"),
        "charging_mode" : "15DAYS",
        "circle_id" : 1,
        "actual_price_deduct" : 30,
        "pack_id" : 162,
        "created" : "01-03-2016 00:12",
        "flag" : 0
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

You are saved created in string format.
Save in Date format then find data by date.